# AWS lambda: "Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'models'"

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, dockerfile, aws-sam

I want to deploy a pytorch model with aws sam. my folder structure looks as follows:

```
├── Dockerfile
├── __init__.py
├── app.py
├── models
│   ├── common.py
│   ├── experimental.py
│   └── yolo.py
├── requirements.txt
└── utils
    ├── autoanchor.py
    ├── datasets.py
    ├── general.py
    ├── google_utils.py
    ├── metrics.py
    ├── plots.py
    └── torch_utils.py
```

As you can see, I have several local dependencies. My Dockerfile looks as follows:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8

COPY app.py requirements.txt ./
ADD models utils ./

RUN python3.8 -m pip install -r requirements.txt -t .

# Command can be overwritten by providing a different command in the template directly.
CMD ["app.lambda_handler"]
```

The code in `app.py` imports modules from `models`. Unfortunately this doesn't work and produces the following error:

```
"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'models'"
```

I have also tried to use `COPY` instead of `ADD` for the directories `models` and `utils`, but it results in the same error. How can I fix this?

Comment: This code is working locally ? Seem like Python packaging for folder is not working so lambda unable to locate `models` package

Comment: No it doesn‘t work locally either. But models is not a python package, but a directory.. so I would have guessed, that the directory is not built correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thing you are missing is if you trying load folder as package you have to create proper packaging in Python. Else you can get all files one by one imported in your `app.py`

Steps to create package :

1. Create folder name `models`
2. Create `__init__.py` file inside `models` folder
3. create your other files like `yolo.py`, `experimental.py`,`common.py` etc
4. Then load all four into `__init__.py` file like below

```
from common import *
from experimental import *
from yolo import *
```

5. Then you can use this in `app.py` like `import models` or `from models import *`

**Note** : Putting all files together into folder not work like package in Python.

Reference code : https://github.com/aviboy2006/flask-rest-api
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is indeed sensible. For some reason, however, it doesn’t solve the issue.. I still get the same error, despite creating the init files

Comment: your locally its running ?

Comment: It doesn't run locally either, I get exactly the same error :/

Comment: It should run I tried ur same folder and files structure

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't, is my Dockerfile correct?

Comment: Ok I figured it out: I had to do `ADD models models` and `ADD utils utils`. Combined with your solution it works now :) Thanks for your help!